# is this a legit "trick" to get the folder a batch file is executing from?

Tags: cmd

I am debugging a complicated script that "works" correctly (even with errors) on a windows 10 system that has the standard 8dot3name convention but fails when the shortened names do not follow the "standard" (whatever that is)

my test batch file is "runtest.bat" and it is in my "documents\win_build" folder

```
@echo off
SET BUILDROOT=%~dps0
ECHO 1------%BUILDROOT%
SET BUILDROOT=%BUILDROOT:\win_bu~1\=%
ECHO 2------%BUILDROOT%
```

the output is

```
C:\Users\josep\Documents\WIN_BUILD>runtest.bat
1------C:\Users\josep\DOCUME~1\WIN_BU~1\
2------C:\Users\josep\DOCUME~1
```

The output needed is that line "2---" which is correct.  Note that there is no trailing backslash which is important***

The problem I have run into is that `win_bu~1` it not always the shorted name. On my NFS the short name for win_build is actually `WOH7UM~G` and the build script will fail.

I can get the actual shortened name with

```
for %%I in (.) do SET SHORT_WIN_BUILD=%%~nsxI
```

The above gives me either win_bu~1 or WOH7UM~G which are correct

Surely there is a better way to get the folder w/o using shortened names.  I am thinking this script was written to be as obtuse as possible.

***  `%~dp0` gets the current directory but has a trailing backslash which I do not know how to remove and do not wish re-write the script to account for the extra backslash.

Comment: `set "fullbuild=%~dp0"`.  Then remove 1 character at the end: `set "fullbuild=%fullbuild:~0,-1%"`.  This does not remove the last directory, though.  But it does remove the last backslash.

Comment: Since the short name is going to be 8 characters, you could `SET BUILDROOT=%BUILDROOT:~0,-10%` to remove the last 10 characters (2 backslashes and whichever 8 shortname characters).  Of course, this will not work if you rename your directory to a name with fewer than 8 characters.

Comment: %~dp0  does not generate a short name so would have to be -12 to get rid of "\win_build\"  seems that 11 should have worked, but 12 was required

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly ("get the parent folder of the folder where the batch file is stored, not necessarily in short format")? If I do: `for %%a in ("%~dp0..") do echo %%~fa`

Comment: Thanks Stephan, that is better:  for %%a in ("%~dp0..") do SET BUILDROOT=%%~fa  and no need to subtract off anything